# How Many Times Would I Need To Draw a Sock to Get a Matching Pair?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I can't figure out this problem.

"There are 30 white socks, 22 black socks, and 14 blue socks scattered across the floor of a dark room.  How many socks would you have to pick up before you had a matching pair?"

So far I understand I have a 45.45% chance of drawing a white sock, a 33.33% chance of drawing a black sock, and a 21.21% chance of drawing a blue sock.  I can't figure out if there is a definitive answer or if it simply comes down to probability and I would have to pick up all of the socks.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider the worst case scenario.  How many socks can you draw before you must draw a second sock of the same color?

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability.  The question means, "What is the smallest number of socks you have to pick up to be certain you have a matching pair."  Hint: It's one more than the maximum number of non-matching socks you can have.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was thinking about it in completely the wrong way :)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Can 4 socks of 3 types be all unpaired? Why?

Comment: I get it!  I was typing a response saying "What if I draw 30 white socks and there's no pair to the blue or black socks?" and realized I'll have plenty of socks to make a pair.  Thank you so much!